# Do I need the same RTK reciever if I want to implement RTK?

Tags: gps

I bought an RTK receiver, only one because I wanted to do some testing before I invested in two receivers. I found one I like more, but if I have two different recievers will the accuracy be reduced because the GPS signal is not being processed in the same way.

Maybe I misunderstand, because I think of RTK as subtraction. The receivers are getting the same signal and then the fixed one is the error so if they aren't processing the signal in the same way then the subtraction won't work as well.

So do I need the same two RTK receivers to get the best results from RTK?